# django import-export "NOT NULL constraint failed"

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I'm pretty new at Django and am stuck trying to implement [Django import-export](https://github.com/bmihelac/django-import-export/blob/master/docs/index.rst).  My three pertinent model are Officer, Incident, and Details.  Officer and Incident are in a M2M relationship through Details.  I have gotten all of the functionality to work besides importing details.  When I try to import via the import button, I get "NOT NULL constraint failed: police_archive_details.incident_id" for each row in the .xls or .csv file I'm importing.

Here's my (current) admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from import_export import resources, widgets, fields
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin, ImportExportActionModelAdmin
from forms import AdminTextForm, OfficerTextForm

from .models import Officer, Incident, Details, SiteText

class FullNameForeignKeyWidget(widgets.ForeignKeyWidget):
    def get_queryset(self, value, row):
        return self.model.objects.filter(
            first_name__iexact=row["first_name"],
            last_name__iexact=row["last_name"]
        )

class DetailsInlineAdmin (admin.TabularInline):
    model = Details
    extra = 5




class OfficerResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Officer

class OfficerAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'badge', 'department')
    search_fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    inlines = [DetailsInlineAdmin]
    resource_class = OfficerResource

    form=OfficerTextForm

    class Media:
        js = ('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js','/static/admin/js/admin/popup.js')



class IncidentResource(resources.ModelResource):

    officer = fields.Field(
        column_name='officer',
        attribute='officer',
        widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(Officer, 'badge'))

    class Meta:
        fields = ('officer',)
        model = Incident   

class IncidentAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('office','case_number')
    search_fields = ['case_number']
    inlines = [DetailsInlineAdmin]
    resource_class = IncidentResource




class DetailsResource(resources.ModelResource):

    officer = fields.Field(
        column_name='officer',
        attribute='officer',
        widget=FullNameForeignKeyWidget(Officer))

    incident = fields.Field(
        column_name='incident',
        attribute='incident',
        widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(Incident, 'case_number'))

    class Meta:
        fields = ('id','incident','officer__last_name','officer__first_name','allegation', 'finding', 'action')
        model = Details


class DetailsAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display=('incident','officer', 'allegation', 'finding', 'action')
    search_fields = ['officer__last_name', 'incident__case_number']
    resource_class = DetailsResource

class SiteTextAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form=AdminTextForm





admin.site.register(Officer, OfficerAdmin)
admin.site.register(Incident, IncidentAdmin)
admin.site.register(Details, DetailsAdmin)
admin.site.register(SiteText, SiteTextAdmin)
```

And here's models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from tinymce import models as tinymce_models

class Officer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    badge = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    model_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to = "police_archive/officer_photos", default= 'noimage', blank=True, null=True)
    description = tinymce_models.HTMLField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.last_name + ', ' + self.first_name

    class Meta():
        ordering = ['last_name']    





class Incident(models.Model):
    officer = models.ManyToManyField(Officer, through='Details')
    case_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

    OFFICE_CHOICES = (
    ('CRA', 'Civilian Review Authority'),
    ('IA', 'Internal Affairs'),
    ('OPCR', 'Office of Police Conduct Review'),
    )
    office = models.CharField(max_length=10,
    choices=OFFICE_CHOICES,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.case_number

    class Meta():
        ordering = ['-case_number']

class Details(models.Model):
    officer = models.ForeignKey(Officer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    incident = models.ForeignKey(Incident, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    allegation = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    finding = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    action = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
            return self.officer.first_name + ' '+ self.officer.last_name+ ', ' + self.incident.case_number

    class Meta():
        verbose_name_plural = "details"
        ordering = ['incident__case_number']


class SiteText(models.Model):
    content1 = tinymce_models.HTMLField()
    content2 = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
```

Comment: you may have a foreign key somewhere named police_archive_details but in the code you provided it is nowhere to be found. Is there some more code (models) ? Anyway, the error shown tells you that the field police_archive_details (which may be a FK Incident) has no incident : is it null but you did not allow that (see incident in Details, add null=True)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Police archive is the application and details is a model.  My code below is working.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I spent all day debugging yesterday and got everything working properly.  Here's my admin.py now, models.py is unchanged.  I forget exactly which change solved the original error I posted about.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from import_export import resources, widgets, fields
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin, ImportExportActionModelAdmin
from forms import AdminTextForm, OfficerTextForm

from .models import Officer, Incident, Details, SiteText

class DetailsInlineAdmin (admin.TabularInline):
    model = Details
    extra = 5




class OfficerResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Officer

class OfficerAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'badge', 'department')
    search_fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    inlines = [DetailsInlineAdmin]
    resource_class = OfficerResource

    form=OfficerTextForm

    class Media:
        js = ('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js','/static/admin/js/admin/popup.js')



class IncidentResource(resources.ModelResource):


    class Meta:
        fields = ('officer','case_number', 'office')
        model = Incident
        import_id_fields = ['case_number']

class IncidentAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('office','case_number')
    search_fields = ['case_number']
    inlines = [DetailsInlineAdmin]
    resource_class = IncidentResource




class DetailsResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class BadgeForeignKeyWidget(widgets.ForeignKeyWidget):
        def get_queryset(self, value, row):
            return self.model.objects.filter(
                badge__iexact=row["badge"]
            )

    officer = fields.Field(
        column_name='officer',
        attribute='officer',
        widget=BadgeForeignKeyWidget(Officer, 'last_name'))

    incident = fields.Field(
        column_name='incident',
        attribute='incident',
        widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(Incident, 'case_number'))

    class Meta:
        fields = ('id','officer','incident', 'allegation', 'finding', 'action')
        model = Details


class DetailsAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display=('incident','officer', 'allegation', 'finding', 'action')
    search_fields = ['officer__last_name', 'incident__case_number']
    resource_class = DetailsResource

class SiteTextAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form=AdminTextForm





admin.site.register(Officer, OfficerAdmin)
admin.site.register(Incident, IncidentAdmin)
admin.site.register(Details, DetailsAdmin)
admin.site.register(SiteText, SiteTextAdmin)
```

Another note is that you need to put an 'id' column in your spreadsheet. I was able to leave mine blank and then Django would generate an id to use as a primary key.